# Dual boot windows machine is slow?

Tags: windows-10, memory, graphics-card, cpu

I have `MSI X99A SLI Plus (MS-7885)` with `Intel xeon E5-2620 v4` CPU with `32 GB` RAM and `4 GB`  Graphic card. This machine works like a charm, I am `ubuntu` user. I decided to install `Dual boot` and after sometime i found out that its super slow for some reason. Can anyone point out me what is wrong with `Windows 10` ?

Here is the [report](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j-I_G6l4uzD8f4qixxcOENzV7SgH51wP/view?usp=sharing) of the `CPUID` if you need to see the configuration.

[image: CPU]
[image: MB]
[image: RAM]
[image: GPU]

Comment: You CPU might be a little slow for single-thread performance, but that hardware is more than sufficient for a win10 build. start by running the built-in memory tester. I had some boxes that ran Win7, but would not correctly upgrade to Win10, and those boxes ran Linux fine. Was never sure what the problem was but the win10 builtin memory tester found it immediately.

Comment: What specific actions are "super slow" to your experience?

Comment: @FrankThomas : I will do that for sure.

Comment: @Robert : I feel like the screen is kind of frozen and while installation it took forever. i have another i3 win10 machine which took couple of sec and this took almost 2/3 min for some reason.